# How to Forward SMS Message to URL

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I used this as my helpguide: [Twilio: Forward received SMS to URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189348/twilio-forward-received-sms-to-url)

But the problem is I cannot extract anything from the set of parameters. 
I'm using Classic ASP and I'm try to capture anything that exists in the `Request.QueryString` by placing it into a database.

All I want to do is to insert the *from phone number* and *body/text message* into my database every time a message is received. All I get is an empty record in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default when Twilio receives an SMS to your Twilio phone number it makes a POST request to your ASP page, sending a set of form-encoded values.  This means you should use:

Request.Form("Body")

If you want Twilio to make a GET request instead, allowing you to use `Request.Querystring`, you can configure that on the [phone number](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming) configuration page in your Twilio Console.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls), the default value for Twilio's `StatusCallbackMethod` is `POST`, so unless you've specified otherwise, you will be receiving your desired parameters in the `POST` body, not in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to forward an SMS to a URL or Rest API there are few android apps that do just that, most of them are paid ones.

This is one example:

https://www.forward-sms-to-rest-api.com